# Google Vision: How do I choose all types of detection

Tags: api, cloud, google-cloud-vision, vision

i'm playing around with **Google Cloud Vision API** and have implemented it on my own application. For now I can only implement one "type" in the POST, but I want to have more than one. In the Vision API - Drag and Drop Demo (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop), you can output more than one type and I want to do the same.

After reading the documentation for the API I thought the solution was to set the "type" to "TYPE_UNSPECIFIED", but after trying that I couldn't get any response.

"type" is a ENUM and I listed the documentation under:

> ```
> *// Type: The feature type.
>     //
>     // Possible values:
>     //   "TYPE_UNSPECIFIED" - Unspecified feature type.
>     //   "FACE_DETECTION" - Run face detection.
>     //   "LANDMARK_DETECTION" - Run landmark detection.
>     //   "LOGO_DETECTION" - Run logo detection.
>     //   "LABEL_DETECTION" - Run label detection.
>     //   "TEXT_DETECTION" - Run text detection / optical character*
> ```

I need help to implement more than one "type"..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#Feature):

> Multiple `Feature` objects can be specified in the `features` list.

So, to implement all types in a POST request to the `annotate` method of the REST API you'd have to give all types in the `features` list like so:

```
"features": [
        {
          "type": "FACE_DETECTION"
        },
        {
          "type": "LANDMARK_DETECTION"
        },
    ...
      ]
```

Comment: Thank you! Missed that line ;)